# Pascal triangle kth coefficient in nth row proof

Tags: pascals-triangle

I would like to know how the below formula holds for a pascal triangle coefficients.

I didn't understand how we get the formula for a given row

nck = (n-k+1/k) * nck-1

Note: if we know the previous coefficient this formula is used to calculate current coefficient in pascal triangle.

FYI: I know nck = n-1ck-1 + n-1ck, but iam not able to deduce above formula

Any help is appreciated?